# How to parse lines from a file on a FTP server without downloading it

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, ftp

I want to **parse** a line from large files on a FTP server **without downloading** them, using Linux command line.

Something like this comes to mind:

```
wget <ftp_file> | grep <something_from_a_line>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general Linux usage issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: You can't parse the data without having first downloaded it. Perhaps you really mean "without first saving it to a file". If that is the case try: `curl <ftp_file> | grep <something>`.

Comment: Your answer solved it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: But you really really should note that curl is still "downloading" the file. It's just that it doesn't get written to file. So it doesn't save any download time or bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a remote file from a client machine implies that you download it (explicitly or implicitly). Otherwise you must find some way to connect onto the server and read the file locally on the server.

Comment: Thanks! Since the files are huge, downloading them is not an option. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @AronvanBeelen : If the file is so big, you could maybe `ssh` to the remote system (or use _telnet_ or something similar) and run the commands on the remote host.